# HTTPs over Bottlepy and Gevent

Tags: python, https, gevent

What is the best way to insert HTTPs in this code?
I need to use Bootlepy and Gevent, like this example.
Thanks

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()

from time import sleep
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "<html><body>hello</body></html>"

@route('/stream')
def stream():
    yield 'START'
    sleep(3)
    yield 'MIDDLE'
    sleep(5)
    yield 'END'

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, server='gevent')
```

Comment: Terminate the HTTPS (TLS) before it gets to your app at something like Nginx/HAProxy. You don't need to worry about it then. Failing that use a different WSGI server. CheeryPy and Gunicorn both support SSL. Sorry I am not familiar with Bottle but there may be an option that I couldn't see.

Answer (score 0):

```
from gevent import pywsgi
import bottle

# Get bottle's WSGI callable
wsgi_app = bottle.default_app()

# Needs a generated SSL key and certificate to use.
server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 443), wsgi_app,
                           keyfile='server.key', certfile='server.crt')
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Does not work :( I generate a cert with: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./cert.key -out ./cert.crt . but i have this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8whglsosxhorp9v/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-20%20at%2003.38.06.png?dl=0